# Calculate the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{c_n}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Calculate the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{c_n}{n}$ for $$c_n=\begin{cases} 3, n=4k+1, k\in \mathbb N \\ -1, n\neq4k+1 \end{cases}$$

**My solution:**
Assuming that $\mathbb N={1,2,...}$ we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{c_n}{n}=-1+(-1\cdot 3)+3+(-1\cdot 3)+3+(-1\cdot 3)+3+...$$However "last word of $c_n$" is infinite so I don't know how I can finish this task because we see that $-3$ shortens periodically from $3$ but I think that I can't write that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{c_n}{n}=-1$.
Can you give your opinion on this subject?

Comment: You better have $0 \in \Bbb N$ because you need $k=0$ to define the term $n=1$

Comment: Can you explain how did you get $-1+(-1\cdot 3)+3+...$?

Comment: @elescararriba $c_1=-1, c_2=c_3=c_4=-1, c_5=3 \Rightarrow c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4+c_5=-1+(-1\cdot 3)+3+...$

Comment: Note that in the sum is $\frac{c_n}{n}$ then $\frac{c_1}{1}+\frac{c_2}{2}+\frac{c_3}{3}+\frac{c_4}{4}+\cdots+$

Comment: Define $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{3 x^{4 k+1}}{4 k+1}-\frac{x^{4 k+2}}{4 k+2}-\frac{x^{4 k+3}}{4 k+3}-\frac{x^{4
   k+4}}{4 k+4}$. It's easy to evaluate $f'(x)$ (geometrical series) and then integrate this over $[0,1]$ to find $f(1)$ which is the sum you are after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}&&\sum_{k\geq 0}\left[\frac{3}{4k+1}-\frac{1}{4k+2}-\frac{1}{4k+3}-\frac{1}{4k+4}\right]\\&=&\sum_{k\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1}(3-x-x^2-x^3)x^{4k}\,dx \\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-x^4}(3-x-x^2-x^3)\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{3+2x+x^2}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2(1+x)+(1+x^2)}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}\,dx =\frac{\pi}{2}+\log(2)\end{eqnarray*}$$
by partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Very intelligent observation with the integral, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Note that the sum consists of blocks of $$\frac 3{4k+1}-\frac 1{4k+2}-\frac 1{4k+3}-\frac 1{4k+4}$$
If you put all these over a common denominator and simplify the $k^3$ terms in the numerator cancel and you are left with 
$$\frac{96k^2+136k+46}{(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+4)}$$
Because this is of order $k^{-2}$ the sum will converge.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%203%2F(4k%2B1)-1%2F(4k%2B2)-1%2F(4k%2B3)-1%2F(4k%2B4)%20from%200%20to%20infinity) gets the sum to be $$\frac \pi 2 + \log(2)$$
Seeing the answer, I am tempted to write
$$\log(2)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac 1{4k+1}-\frac 1{4k+2}+\frac 1{4k+3}-\frac 1{4k+4}$$
and try to get
$$\frac \pi 2=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac 1{4k+1}-\frac 1{4k+3}=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 2{(4k+1)(4k+3)}$$

Comment: The beginning of your answer is very interesting, but how to calculate $ \sum_ {k = 0}^{+ \infty} \frac {96k ^ 2 + 136k + 46} {(4k + 1) (4k + 2) (4k + 3 ) (4k + 4)} $ not using hints from Wolfram? I will not be able to access it on the exam, and this is a task from one of the old exams, so there must be a way to count it without

Comment: You don't really need to calculate it.  You can just show the $k^3$ terms cancel, which you can do by hand, and you have convergence

Comment: I think that you don't have right because in this task I have "calculate" not "investigate convergence"

Comment: But first you need to show convergence to make sure the calculation makes sense.  I agree I didn't finish the last part of the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

As Ross Millikan wrote, consider the partial sum
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac 3{4k+1}-\frac 1{4k+2}-\frac 1{4k+3}-\frac 1{4k+4}\right)$$ and remember that
$$T(a,b)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{ak+b}=\frac{H_{n+\frac{b}{a}}-H_{\frac{b}{a}}}{a}$$ where appear harmonic numbers and that the expansion for large values of $n$ is given by
$$T(a,b)=\frac{\log \left({n}\right)+\gamma-H_{\frac{b}{a}} }{a}+\frac{a+2 b}{2 a^2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
So,
$$S_n=3T(4,1)-T(4,2)-T(4,3)-T(4,4)=\left(\frac{\pi }{2}+\log (2)-\frac{23}{12}\right)-\frac{3}{8n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which gives the limit and shows how it is approached.